# Why does ALTER INDEX block system tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

When I run a simple alter non clustered column stored index query on table `dbo.SampleDataTable` (>50 million records):

```
 ALTER INDEX CCI_SampleDataTable
    ON dbo.SampleDataTable REBUILD
```

it blocks system tables `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS`.

The problem is our Reporting Server - Tableau Server. When user runs Tableau Report which uses a stored procedure in the database as a data source, Tableau Server sends this query to the database:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES R 
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS P ON R.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = P.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA 
                                     AND R.SPECIFIC_NAME = P.SPECIFIC_NAME 
                                     AND R.ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' 
                                     AND R.ROUTINE_SCHEMA <>'SYS'
```

and this query will be blocked when the ETL Process run ALTER INDEX QUERY.

Because that is the internal query from Tableau, I can't modify it with `NOLOCK`.
As far as I know, when `ALTER INDEX` runs, the system tables will be updated in real time therefore it will be blocked.

This problem of the system tables is very bad for us because the user can't access to report sometime.

Can you please help me with this problem? What should I do?

The stored procedure which is used by Tableau Report is very simple:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectAllCustomers 
    @CustName VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.SampleDataTable   
    WHERE CustName =@CustName
GO;
```

Comment: If you use the ONLINE option, does the blocking persist? Example: ALTER INDEX [IX_Test] ON [dbo].[Test] REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON);

Comment: i did'nt try it but what will REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON) do?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 "Specifies whether underlying tables and associated indexes are available for queries and data modification during the index operation. The default is OFF."

Comment: Run the ALTER INDEX statement outside of peak use hours. Also, you'll need Enterprise Edition of SQL Server to use the ONLINE option

Comment: @Jon that depends on their version of SSMS. Different years had different features. 2008 for example had online available  for almost all editions as I recall

Comment: I have tried with ONLINE Option but it doesn’t help

Comment: Try to avoid using the term “bug” for unknown behavior / unexpected behavior. A “bug” is in violation of specified behavior or previously defined/accepted behavior - as such, the specified behavior definition can usually be included as a reference. This was not done or demonstrated in the question and thus there is no need to claim a “bug”.